# How many ways to split a convex polygon to squares?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, catalan-numbers, lagrange-inversion

If $a_0 = 0$ and $a_1 = 1$, and $a_n$ stands for the number of ways to split a convex polygon with $n+1$ angles to squares, is given by

$$a_n = \sum_{k+l+m = n }a_ka_la_m$$

Now, using generating function, I'm supposed to get a functional equation.

1. How can I find it?
2. After I find it, I'm supposed to use Lagrange's inversion theorem in order to find the general solution for $a_n$.

Comment: Hint: $$\color{red}{???} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( a_n - \sum_{i+j+k=n} a_ia_ja_k\right) z^n \stackrel{\color{red}{\text{WHY?}}}{=}
\sum_{n=0}^1 \left(a_n - \sum_{i+j+k=n} a_ia_ja_k\right) z^n\\
= (a_0 - a_0^3) + (a_1 - 3a_0^2a_1) z = z$$

Comment: Importantly, your recurrence is only valid when $n\neq 1$. Note $a_1\neq 3a_0a_0a_1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can help you with finding the functional equation, but not with the Lagrange inversion.

The recurrence is valid only when $n\neq 1$.

Let $A(x) = \sum_{n\ge 1}a_{n}x^n$. Note that $\sum_{k+l+m=n}a_ka_la_m$ is equal to the coefficient of $x^n$ in $A(x)^3$. Therefore,
$$
A(x) = a_1x+\sum_{n\ge 2}a_nx^n =x+\sum_{n\ge 2}[\text{coef of $x^n$ in $A(x)^3$}]x^n=x+A(x)^3.
$$

Comment: (+1) BTW, Lagrange inversion give us
$$
A(x)  = x{}_2F_1\left(\frac13,\frac23;\frac32\;\frac{27x^2}{4}\right)
= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(3k)!}{(2k+1)!k!}x^{2k+1}$$
which also have a nice closed from expression 
$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \sin\left[\frac13\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}x\right)\right]$$
see [OEIS A001764](https://oeis.org/A001764).